# How to get free space amount for tablespace in postgresql 9.1?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

AFAIK, PostgreSQL `VACUUM` command only marks as free space occupied by deleted tuples and never shrinks the datafile itself. So it's impossible to tell how much space is considered "free" by DBMS itself.

Is there any good way to tell how much space in a datafile is actually occupied by data (or indexes or whatever else) and how much is free to use?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage has some pretty good queries.

Comment: @Greg Those aren't the queries I'm looking for. They don't say anything about the difference between the size of datafile and net size of it's contents.

Answer (score 4):

The [`pgstattuple`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstattuple.html) module can provide this information.

In the doc example:

```
test=> SELECT * FROM pgstattuple('pg_catalog.pg_proc');
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+-------
table_len          | 458752
tuple_count        | 1470
tuple_len          | 438896
tuple_percent      | 95.67
dead_tuple_count   | 11
dead_tuple_len     | 3157
dead_tuple_percent | 0.69
free_space         | 8932
free_percent       | 1.95
```

`free_space` would be what you're looking for. It's the number of bytes not occupied by actual data, counting previously-vacuumed rows and also space between rows due to a custom fill factor or loosely-packed data.

Also, *never shrinks the datafile* is not strictly true for `VACUUM`. It may shrink it if the free space happens to be at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is usually called "table bloat", the ratio between used and free pages in a table.

See:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstattuple.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgfreespacemap.html
- http://www.cybertec.at/detecting-table-bloat/
- http://www.cybertec.at/table-bloat-revisited-making-tables-shrink/

A simple query is:

```
create extension pgfreespacemap;

select pg_size_pretty(sum(avail)) from pg_freespace('mytable'::regclass);
```

Unlike `pgstattuple`, `pg_freespace` doesn't have to scan the whole table, so it's more practical for very big tables.

Note, however, that not all space in a table is *usable* space. It's generally more informative to ignore pages with only few hundred bytes free, e.g. add a `where avail > 100` clause, or similar.